# MySQL add number to count result

Tags: mysql

How can I add a fixed number, say, 2000 to the result of a MySQL COUNT?

At the moment I am trying

```
SELECT count(*) AS `count`
FROM `Database`
WHERE val = 2000
AS sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the fixed value in the `SELECT` as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 2000 AS `count`
FROM `TableName`
WHERE <condition>
```